# generate_n using lambda and back_inserter in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I've recently started using new C++11 features like lambda expressions to make my code easier to read.

In this example, I want to generate a vector of numbers [0 to n] sorted randomly. I have some code similar to the following

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>
    using namespace std;
    void _generateRandomIndices(vector<unsigned int> & indices,
                const unsigned int & n) {
        indices.clear();
        unsigned int i = 0;
        generate_n(back_inserter(indices), n , [&i] ()-> unsigned int{ 
                                                              return i++;
                                                                     } );
        random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end());
    }
```

However, using g++ 4.6 on windows(with the -std=c++0x flag) threw me the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'generate_n(std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<unsigned int> >, const unsigned int&, _generateRandomIndices(std::vector<unsigned int>&, const unsigned int&)::<lambda()>)'
```

What is the right way to use a lambda expression in this case ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in C++11 you can use [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead. And your code compiles fine for me (mingw32 4.6.1).

Comment: I've been out of the C++ loop for a while, so a guess: could it be the `const n` not matching the function signature of `generate_n`?  Which brings me to a question I had about the code: why take a `const` reference to an `unsigned int`, and not just an `unsigned int`?  It's a simple type, so the copy shouldn't cost more than passing by reference, and it's just as safe.

Comment: Note that passing by reference to effectively return a new value is not idiomatic in C++11 -- move semantics will make returning by value efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing an `#include <algorithm>`, since [GCC 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/6Xgqq) aswell as MSVC10 compile the following code without error:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void _generateRandomIndices(vector<unsigned int> & indices,
        const unsigned int & n) {
    indices.clear();
    unsigned int i = 0;
    generate_n(back_inserter(indices), n , [&i] ()-> unsigned int{ 
                                                          return i++;
                                                                 } );
    random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end());
}

int main(){
}
```

Comment: Actually i did included all those headers, i putted just the necessary code

Comment: @sohaibafifi: If you indeed included everything, then your stdlib may be broken. Either you got an include path to the C++03 stdlib, or something else is wrong. Which GCC port for Windows do you use?

Comment: @sohaibafifi: Then double-check your include path and look into the `<algorithm>` header found there. It sounds very much like your stdlib and/or stdlib path are broken.

Comment: Ok i will, it uses the generate_n from MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++\bits\algorithmfwd.h

Comment: @sohaibafifi : I've never had anything but trouble with mainline MinGW. I recommend trying [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) instead.

Comment: @sohaibafifi: Are you sure it will use that? Do you maybe have your own header named `algorithm` (without suffix) that is found before the stdlib header?

Comment: Removing all the MinGW dir and re-installing the 4.5.2 version then adding the -std=c++0x parameter fixed the problem. Thank you. @ildjarn now really i'm thinking to migrate, thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should add this compiller option -std=c++0x

Comment: Without that compiler option, GCC would choke on the lambda, not the `generate_n` algorithm.

Comment: i do, despite it is enabled by default in g++ 4.6

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html GCC provides experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support can be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options. On my Gcc 4.5 this code compiles with this option